# How to write degree symbol in a csv file in python and read the same file as a pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have to write temperature data in a csv file in python. Then I have to read that csv file as a pandas dataframe. The headers are supposed to show Degree Fahrenheit symbol.

My code so far:

```
with open("demo.csv", 'w') as infile:
    writer = csv.writer(infile)
    headers=["day","Average Temperature ((the degree symbol)F)"]
    writer.writerow(headers)
    # then the rest of the code for reading values
```

I know I have to read the csv file as

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_csv("demo.csv")
```

But I am not sure if this will correctly display the degree fahrenheit symbol.
Kindly suggest what to do.

Comment: The degree symbol ° has unicode U00B0. Can you just write that directly?

Comment: I wrote  - "with open('data_weather.csv', 'w', encoding='U00B0') as f" but it showed the error "LookupError: unknown encoding: U00B0".

Comment: The encoding is not U00B0. 00B0 is the unicode code for the degree symbol. When you are typing it in to most programs, you press ctrl+shift+U, then type 00B0, then space and you'll see °. The encoding is "utf-8".

Comment: I encoded as "utf-8" and it worked. Thanks.